# How to move shardlets to a different shard using Elastic Scale in code

Tags: c#, azure-elastic-scale

Reading the documentation of Elastic Scale it appears as usually when moving shardlets one would use the Split/Merve/Move service. 
My question now is, how can I trigger a move of a shardlet in code? Could I trigger the service "api" as demonstrated in *Microsoft.Azure.SqlDatabase.ElasticScale.Service.SplitMerge -> SplitMerge.psm1*. And how well does that scale, e.g. when multiple Shardlets are moved in parallel, independently or does it queue moves? 
Or is there some other way which I have missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your question. Right now, the approach in the PowerShell script is the best option you have. However, we are not particularly happy with that and would like to replace it with proper APIs. I'll be in touch with you to find out more about how your automation environment will look like to get a sense for the proper API for you.

BTW: Different split/merge requests (the ones that show with different OperationIds in the RequestStatus table) are processed sequentially right now. You can play with the BatchSize parameter on your requests. While designed to give a way to control how many shardlets are marked offline in the shard map at a time, larger batch sizes may also give you better performance.

Although this may sound like a sales pitch: The most effective way to improve performance for split/merge operations in our experiments was to use more powerful service tiers in Azure DB for the shards. You can change the service tier dynamically on source and target shard when you know that you have to perform a split or merge on them - and then dial it back down again once the operation is complete.

Hope this helps.

Thanks,
Torsten